# How can i make an animation happen when i click a button ? NEXT.JS

Tags: javascript, next.js, hook

I recently started a project with Next.js to build a portfolio with the purpose of learning to use the framework and I'm facing a wall.

I would like to make an animation happen when I click on a button, my animation is made of images and css wrapped in a component that I import and that looks like this :

```js
import styles from "./loading_ui.module.css";

export default function Loading_ui() {

  return (
    <div id="loading">
      <img className={styles.image_nr} src="https://i.ibb.co/NyYYCcr/Group.png" alt="c1" />
      <img className={styles.image} src="https://i.ibb.co/8b9yg2h/Group-2.png" alt="c1" />
      <img className={styles.image_outer} src="https://i.ibb.co/ZfqRL00/cb1.png" alt="c1" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

My problem does not concern that point but another.
After I click the button, what I'm trying to code is to make the whole content of my page disappear then the images just show-up to make the animation runs, during this time the page corresponding to the button I clicked should be pre-fetched then after a certain delay the user would been redirected to the required page. It isn't working showing me errors about the "Hook" i made.

This code part is an entire component called "Homebuttons" that I import on my main page and that looks like this :

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import styles from "./homeButtons.module.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';

export default function HomeButtons() {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [animationActive, setAnimationActive] = useState(false);

  const handleMyWorkClick = () => {
    setAnimationActive(true);
  };

  const handleMeClick = () => {
    setAnimationActive(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (animationActive) {
      // Démarrez l'animation (ajoutez une classe CSS pour la transition)
      document.body.classList.add("fade-out");
      document.title = "Loading...";

      // Attendez la fin de l'animation (la durée de l'animation CSS + une petite marge)
      const animationDuration = 500; // Durée de l'animation en millisecondes
      setTimeout(() => {
        // Redirigez vers la page souhaitée après l'animation
        if ( usePathname() === "/mywork") {
          router.push("/mywork");
        } else if (usePathname() === "/me") {
          router.push("/me");
        }
      }, animationDuration + 100); // Utilisez une marge de 100 ms pour s'assurer que l'animation est terminée
    }
  }, [animationActive, router]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleMyWorkClick} id="my_work" className={styles.cybr_btn}>
        My Work<span aria-hidden>_</span>
        <span aria-hidden className={styles.cybr_btn__glitch}>
          爪ㄚ 山ㄖ尺Ҝ
        </span>
        <span aria-hidden className={styles.cybr_btn__tag}>
          R25
        </span>
      </button>

      <button onClick={handleMeClick} id="me" className={styles.cybr_btn}>
        Me<span aria-hidden>_</span>
        <span aria-hidden className={styles.cybr_btn__glitch}>
          爪ㄖ
        </span>
        <span aria-hidden className={styles.cybr_btn__tag}>
          R25
        </span>
      </button>

    </div>
  );
}
```

The code i'snt complete since I'm facing the error that I'm trying to fix, and here comes the problem. My buttons are showing correctly when i go to my live preview, they do send the fade-out class to my body when I click on them but after the delay I set, nothing happens but an error code that tells me :

`Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.`

I already checked for the docs but I do not realize how to fix my problem.

I'm trying to get my code to bring the user to the page he selects clicking on the button but i don't figure how to make that "hook" working. Can someone please try to tell me ?

Thanks for reading !

(using latest Next.js version)